# Program Has Unexpectedly Finished

Tags: c++

My execution program won't work properly, for whatever reason.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
    #include <tinyxml/tinyxml.h>
    #include "classowner.h"
    #include "character.h"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        Character * holland = new Character("Holland", HUMAN, MALE);
        delete &holland;
        std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

All my output states is that the program won't execute properly. The output doesn't display, however when I don't allocate the object, it will. Obviously, it's the object. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

It appears the problem may be something more than deleting and allocating memory. Thus, I'm going to post the implementation behind the Character class.

Header:

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef CHARACTER_H
#define CHARACTER_H

enum Race {HUMAN, DARK_ELF};
enum Gender {MALE, FEMALE};
class Character
{
public:
    Character();
    Character(std::string char_name, Race char_race, Gender char_gender);
    ~Character();

    int get_id() { return this->char_id; }
    std::string get_name() { return this->name; }
    Race get_race() { return this->race; }
    Gender get_gender() { return this->gender; }

private:
    int char_id;
    static int * char_count;
    std::string name;
    Race race;
    Gender gender;
};



  #endif // CHARACTER_H
```

//Source:

```
#include "character.h"
#include <iostream>

int * Character::char_count = 0;

Character::Character()
{
    this->char_id = *char_count;
    char_count++;
}

Character::Character(std::string char_name, Race char_race, Gender char_gender)
{
    this->char_id = *char_count;
    char_count++;
    this->name = char_name;
    this->race = char_race;
    this->gender = char_gender;
}

Character::~Character()
{

}
```

Comment: You're deleting the memory which contains the pointer to your real object, which might not be in the heap/dynamic memory to release. Good that you've got exception. Sometimes, releasing wrong memory could end you up in serious memory corruption which requires hell lot of effort to figure out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you try to dereference a null pointer:

```
int * Character::char_count = 0;
```

Both constructors of `class Character` do this

```
this->char_id = *char_count;
```

and that's an attempt to dereference a null pointer. That code makes no sense to me, I guess you could just use `int` instead of pointer:

```
int Character::char_count = 0;
//then
this->char_id = char_count;
```

Also here:

```
Character * holland = new Character("Holland", HUMAN, MALE);
```

you create an object of type `class Character`. You have to delete that object through a pointer to `class Character` - the pointer should have type `Character*`. Instead you try to use `delete` on a pointer of type `Character**`and that leads to undefined behavior.

So instead of

```
delete &holland;
```

you have to use

```
delete holland;
```

Comment: Rebuilt with the fix. Unfortunately, the same thing is happening still :(. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Holland: That should have fixed the initial problem. Maybe there's something with how `Character` class is implemented. You didn't show it to us.

Answer (score 4):

```
delete &holland;
```

should be

```
delete holland;
```

Less profanity would be appreciated.

On the other hand, posting a short example that succinctly illustrates the problem is very much appreciated.

Comment: LOL, I may be a prude but I'm not a censor!